# How to compare these two string

Tags: c#, sql

I have a question for how to compare two strings.

here is the code.

```
        string stringA = "This is a test item";
        string stringB = "item test a is This";
```

Obviously, stringB contains every words from stringA, but in a different order.

My desired result should be TRUE.

My question is, what should I do? I have tried to use the .Contains() method, but the result is FALSE.

Thanks everyone.

**UPDATES**

Thanks everyone for the kindly replies.

**Here is my clarification**

I am actually building a database search function by using LINQ and EF.

Assume that, an item has its name as "This is a test item".

If user input "test a is this", I would like the function smart enough to catch the item mentioned above.

Any suggestion?

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Thanks again for all your help.

I do like Peter Ritchie's, codesparkle's, Dave's and EdFred's suggestion.

Comment: Are your strings in an actual database? If so, you should tag this question with `SQL`, since that's what you'll need to write your function with.

Comment: See my answer below.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index sounds like what you are trying to do via EF.

Comment: It's nice to know what you're actual success criteria is up front so this doesn't just turn into a long discussion and risk getting closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Peter Richie's excellent suggestion, using `Array.Sort()` instead of `List<T>.Sort()`, without the duplication but packed into a neat extension method:

```
public static bool ContainsSameWordsAs(this string first, string second)
{
    return first.GetSortedWords().SequenceEqual(second.GetSortedWords());
    // if upper and lower case words should be seen as identical, use:
    // StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase as a second argument to SequenceEqual
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetSortedWords(this string source)
{
    var result = source.Split().ToArray();
    Array.Sort(result);
    return result;
}
```

**Usage**

```
string stringA = "This is a test item";
string stringB = "item test a is This";
string stringC = "Not the Same is This";
bool result = stringA.ContainsSameWordsAs(stringB);    // true
bool different = stringA.ContainsSameWordsAs(stringC); // false
```

---

**Edit:** <del>It's hard to understand why you accepted an answer that does not comply with the requirements stated in your question.</del> If you really want the strings `"This is a test item"` and `"test a is this"` to match, you'd need to use something a bit more involved, such as:

```
public static bool ContainsSameWordsAs(this string first, string second)
{
    var ignoreCase = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
    return first.Split().Any(word => second.Split().Contains(word, ignoreCase));
}
```

You may want to come up with a better algorithm though, as this one is extremely loose -- two identical words will be enough to count as a match. But this one *will* match your requirements as stated in the question.

Comment: Hi buddy, the answer I accepted didn't cover everything. The most important thing in his suggestion is the Inverted index part. Thanks a lot for your kindly help. :)

Comment: what if stringB = "item test a is This ok hello"

Comment: @user361022 I'm glad to help, but you might need to clarify that a bit. Do all elements of stringA have to be in stringB, but not vice versa? or does at least one word have to be contained in both? or at least half the words has to be contained in both?

Answer (score 6):

'String.Split' the words with a space delimiter, sort the resulting array into a List, then compare the list.  For example:

```
var x = new List<string>(stringA.Split(' '));
x.Sort();
var y = new List<string>(stringB.Split(' '));
y.Sort();
bool areEqual = x.SequenceEqual(y);
```

**UPDATE** If you want case-insensitive:

```
var x = new List<string>(stringA.Split(' '));
x.Sort();
var y = new List<string>(stringB.Split(' '));
y.Sort();
bool areEqual = x.SequenceEqual(y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

But, if you're looking for something that will be executed in SQL Server, then you'll likely need something else.

Comment: You need to convert to lower here. It won't work in this case: string stringA = "This is a TEST item";
          string stringB = "item test a is This";

Comment: and where is that requirement stated, @Dave?

Comment: @PeterRitchie right here: "Assume that, an item has its name as "This is a test item".

If user input "test a is this", I would like the function smart enough to catch the item mentioned above."

Comment: @Dave that seems like a typo to me, since the OP especially spelled `This` with a capital `T` in his code sample.

Comment: @codesparkle If you were building your own database search would you want only exact matching or all instances? Which is more intelligent? Look at his edits, see the "clarification" part?

Comment: @Dave if you go by the clarification, none of these answers are correct.

Comment: @Dave, that was added after I posted my answer.  Always fun to try and catch up with changing requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach:

- Get each word in each string into an array of strings
- Sort each array of words in alphabetical order
- Compare the arrays for equality

Answer (score 2):

I would split the string in to tokens and test that all tokens in stringA exist in the token list for stringB.  Something like:

```
var stringBTokens = stringB.Split(" ");
foreach(string token in stringA.Split(" "))
{
    if(stringBTokens.Contains(token) == false) return false;
}
return true;
```

There may be some weird regular expression that can do this, but this is a fairly straight forward test.  If you want to get fancy you could use the Linq Any method as well like this:

```
var stringBTokens = stringB.Split(" ");
return !stringBTokens.Any(token => stringA.Contains(token));
```

This is basically doing the same thing, just the latter I find a bit more elegant.  I hope there are no errors, I'm on my macbook pro and don't have anything .net related (or mono, etc...) installed to verify this works.

**Update**

Based on your clarification, I would have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index

This sounds like what you are trying to achieve.  I have created these before to do rapid text searches in a database and it works very effectively.

Comment: He didn't convert toLower. It won't work in this case: string stringA = "This is a TEST item"; string stringB = "item test a is This";

Answer (score 2):

Modeled after Bernard's explanation.

A lot of people left out a key part. You need to convert the strings .ToLower() before you make a comparison.

EDIT: This is what you need. Made it more readable with Linq.

```
 public static bool Compare (string wordOne, string wordTwo)
    {
        //split into words
        var wordsOne = wordOne.ToLower().Split(' ').ToList();
        var wordsTwo = wordTwo.ToLower().Split(' ').ToList();

        if (wordsOne.Count() != wordsTwo.Count()) {
            return false;
        }

        //sort alphabetically
        wordsOne.Sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x, y));
        wordsTwo.Sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x, y));

        //compare
        for (int i = 0; i < wordsOne.Count(); i++) {
            if(wordsOne[i] != wordsTwo[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You're right of course: a function that ignores case makes a lot more sense. However, in the clarification, one word is missing from the second string yet the OP wants it to return true! As far as I know, nobody has come up with an answer for *that*.

Answer (score 1):

```
stringA.OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(stringB.OrderBy(c => c));
```

**Edit**
Oops. Wrong approach. That'll teach me to answer too fast.

I believe this should work:

```
stringA.Split(' ').OrderBy(w => w).SequenceEqual(stringB.Split(' ').OrderBy(w => w));
```

Comment: Because that checks for characters being the same, not words.

Comment: OK. I'm confused. Can you give me two strings where this will fail?

Comment: OK: "carpet cleaner" and "pet cleaner car". Your function will say they are equal.

Comment: Where's your toLower()? string stringA = "This is a TEST item";
          string stringB = "item test a is This"; will be false

Comment: I dunno. Maybe he cared that the words had the same case. Figured that was a detail the OP could deal with. :) And your solution works as well Dave, I just like my one liner better :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do a 2 stage comparison:

1. Split the strings by ' ' using the .Split(' ') method and ensure they have the same number of elements (.Count property).
2. Cast the newly created arrays (split strings) as Sets and do a A set-difference B Union B set-difference A.

Then iff test 1 passes and there are no elements in the set created by the unions of the set differences (in test 2), you have successfully compared the words in the strings as described above.

Michael G.

Comment: Will this method work with the strings: "a b b a" and "a a a b" ?

Comment: @aquinas Test mine too! Why aren't more people upvoting mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the strings on white space and compare the two resulting collections. You can use [set operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx) from linq:

If the words from the first string are in collection words1, and words from the second string are in words2 you can perform the following operation:

```
if(!words1.Intersect(words2).Except( words1).Any()) -> your sentences are 'equal'
```

Comment: string words1 = "a a b";
string words2 = "a a b";
var q = words1.Intersect(words2) == words1;

will return false

Comment: You're partially right, and partially wrong. You're right, because I tested for object equality, and not set equality. I edited my answer to correct my mistake. And wrong, because I said that words1 and words2 are collections of words from string1 and string2, and not strings themselves. Either way, it does not matter now, that the question was edited to ask for something different :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool match = true;
        string[] stringBSplit = stringB.Split(' ');
        foreach (string aString in stringA.Split((' ')))
        {
            if (!stringBSplit.Contains(aString))
            {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for a lot of different inputs. For example: stringA = "a" and stringB="abc". Your function would return true

Comment: string stringA = "a a b"; 
string stringB = "a b";

Will fail now though.